# How should i use WellKnownTypes with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, grpc

I am using protobuf and I use Int32Value from https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf
if I write `import "google/protobuf/any.proto";` i get the following error `google/protobuf/any.proto: File not found.` I haven't found any documentation about it.
I can't find a way. How should I use these types?

Answer (score 4):

I have found an answer. There are proto files on Google.Protobuf.Tools.* package in packages\Google.Protobuf.Tools.*\tools\google\protobuf.
You should add `-I=path_to_proto_files_in_nuget` and add `import "wrappers.proto";` to the header of your proto file.

Comment: Thanks a LOT. I have been trying to do this, but google's documentation is very cryptic about this.